# Python 2.7 [Errno 113] No route to host

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I have 2 computers on the same LAN. The first PC has an ip address 192.168.178.30, the other PC has an ip address 192.168.178.26.
Ping, traceroute, telnet, ssh, everything works between the two PCs. Both PCs run the same OS - CentOS 7 and both PCs have the same python version 2.7.5 (checked with the python -V command).

I copied simple python code from a computer networking book.

client.py

```
from socket import *
serverName = '192.168.178.30'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
sentence = raw_input('Input lowercase sentence: ')
clientSocket.send(sentence)
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print 'From Server:', modifiedSentence
clientSocket.close()
```

server.py

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('192.168.178.30',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(5)
print 'The server is ready to receive'
while 1:
       connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
       sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
       capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
       connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence)
       connectionSocket.close()
```

The code works when it is ran on the same PC (where the server is listening on localhost).
When I run the client code on one PC and the server code on the other PC I get this error on the client side.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 5, in <module>
    clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you add the network configuration (`ip addr`) of both machines to your question? This seems to be more of a network problem than one with the Python API.

Comment: i was behind cloudflare and that sorted out. its working. check your firewall or any external security configurations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the firewall (on the server).

Comment: @ThePraetor: Did you just delete your comment on this answer? If disabling the firewall worked, I'd actually be curious on where you disabled it, because when it was the server firewall, I was obviously wrong in my other comment about the 'No route to host' message.

Comment: I added an answer. Deleted my comment by mistake :(.

Answer (score 7):

I stopped the firewall like Messa suggested and now it works.

```
service firewalld stop
```

I still don't understand what the problem was. I even tried using different distributions. Do all distributions have strict firewalls or something. For example Ubuntu to Ubuntu, Ubuntu to CentOS, CentOS to Ubuntu I still had the same problem (error).

Comment: I'm on a Mac and if I run `service` I get `-bash: service: command not found`. What do I do? I know this would work on Linux, but a few days ago I switched to macOS. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

None of this stuff worked for me. I just connected both the devices to the same WiFi network and my program worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
~]#supervisord
Error: No config file found at default paths (/usr/etc/supervisord.conf, /usr/supervisord.conf, supervisord.conf, etc/supervisord.conf, /etc/supervisord.conf); use the -c option to specify a config file at a different path
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

You should use
`ln -s /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf /usr/etc/supervisord.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this same error ([Errno 113] No route to host) if you are trying to connect 2 devices on the same network. the error can be fixed by double checking to make sure both devices are connected to the mqtt_client or whatever you are using. as soon as I connected the device I was trying to talk to everything worked as to be expected.I would also check to make sure the right IP_Address is being passed

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem. I am putting our findings here in case anyone else stumbles across this question like I did.

Our configuration:

- Host A: IP address 192.168.0.1, netmask 255.255.255.0
- Host B: IP address 192.168.1.1, netmask 255.255.**254**.0

Neither host has a default gateway.

We are connecting from Host B to Host A. (That is not a typo.) The `connect` call succeeds, but when we try to `send` data, we get errno 113 aka. EHOSTUNREACH aka. "No route to host".

The fix, of course, was to change the subnet on Host A to match Host B.

We were surprised to see this error on a connection within the same subnet / same LAN. And we were surprised that `connect` succeeded followed by `send` failing. And we were surprised to see this error on Host B even though the network configuration on Host B itself was fine.

Somehow, the incorrect subnet on Host A caused this error on Host B...

...and just like that, today I learned about ICMP "destination unreachable" messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
service firewalld stop
```

This helped me. I turned them off on both devices to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by misconfigured network, particularly invalid entry in the ARP table.
First step in troubleshooting is to `ping` a known server, for example:

`$ ping www.google.com`

If it fails with "Destination Host Unreachable", it would basically confirm that something is wrong with the network configuration.
Next, run `ip neighbor show`.
The sample output below shows a misconfigured IP for the gateway: 192.136. instead of 192.168.:

```
[vadmin@fractal ~]$ ip neighbor show
192.168.1x.x2 dev enp42s0 lladdr 4c:32:75:92:8d:xx DELAY 
192.168.1x.x36 dev enp42s0 lladdr 80:ee:73:40:64:xx STALE 
192.136.1x.x2 dev enp42s0 FAILED
```

After correcting the address, the problem has been resolved.